# How to enable login option while configuring my Nuget (private) feed in visual studio

Tags: authentication, telerik, nuget, nuget-server, telerik-open-access

I want to enable the login option for Nuget feeding in visual studio.

If a user configures my feed in visual studio. I want to enable login option. The login popup contains email and password (I have a database for user details). After successfully user login then allows the user to use the packages.

I have configured our own NuGet feed using **NuGet Server**. I have used the **latest version (3.1.2)**
https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Server/releases

I have referred Telerik. They achieve this option.
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/installation/installing-the-telerik-controls-from-nuget-package#telerik-nuget-feed-in-visual-studio

Telerik Feed link.
https://nuget.telerik.com/nuget

How to achieve this? Is there anyone have the idea related to this?

Thanks for your help advance.